# word.shape.name throwing Exception

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, interop

I am working on `Word AddIns` and using `Interop library` of `Word` and i want to assign a name(string) to Shape but word.shape.name throwing Exception:

> "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))".

My code is:

```
        bool blnRetVal = false;
        string strModel = ndModel.Name;
        int lngModel = 0;
        int lngNextModel = 0;
        int lngStart;
        int lngEnd;
        Alias.Document objTemp;
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range objRange;
        Shape objShape;
        Object[] astr;
        int n;
        bool bLastModel;
        /*'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        '   1. Find model's model marker and the next marker (if any)
        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        astr = dicMarkers.Keys();
        for (n = astr.GetLowerBound(0); n <= astr.GetUpperBound(0); n++)
        {
            if (string.Compare(astr[n].ToString(), strModel, true) == 0)
            {
                lngModel = (int)dicMarkers.get_Item(astr[n]);   //PNDC  //dicMarkers.Item(astr(n))
                if (n < astr.GetUpperBound(0))
                {
                    if (string.Compare(astr[n + 1].ToString(), "#end", true) == 0)
                    {
                        lngNextModel = 0;
                        bLastModel = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lngNextModel = (int)dicMarkers.get_Item(astr[n + 1]);
                        bLastModel = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lngNextModel = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        /*'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        '   2. Copy model from original document to new document
        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        if (lngModel > 0)
        {
            lngStart = objSourceDocument.Sections[lngModel].Range.Start;
            if (lngNextModel == 0)
            {
                var key = "#end";
                var value = dicMarkers.get_Item(key);
                lngEnd = value;
            }
            else
                lngEnd = objSourceDocument.Sections[lngNextModel].Range.Start; //objSourceDocument.Sections.Last.Index;

            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //copy original
            objSourceDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.SetRange(lngStart, lngEnd);
            objSourceDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
            bool bInsertSection = false;
            //paste (append) copied model to the document
            if (objTargetDocument.Sections.First.Index == objTargetDocument.Sections.Last.Index)
            {
                //Target document only has 1 (default) section
                bInsertSection = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (objTargetDocument.Sections.Last.PageSetup.SectionStart == WdSectionStart.wdSectionNewPage)
                {
                    //Last section is a nextpage section
                    if ((objTargetDocument.Sections.Last.Range.End - (objTargetDocument.Sections.Last.Range.Start) <= 1))
                        //Empty section
                        bInsertSection = false;
                    else
                        bInsertSection = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Last section isn't a nextpage
                    bInsertSection = true;
                }

            }

            objTargetDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Start = objTargetDocument.Range().End;
            if (bInsertSection)
            {
                objTargetDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage);
                objTargetDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Start = objTargetDocument.Range().End;
            }

            objTargetDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Collapse();
            objRange = objTargetDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.Duplicate; //remember range for model marker anchor
            objTargetDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste();

            //place model marker (so that we can find our model again)
            objShape = objTargetDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationUpward, 0, 0, 0, 0, objRange);

            objShape.Name = m_strModelMarker + strModel;
            objShape.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;

            UpdateFields(ref objTargetDocument, ref ndModel);
            blnRetVal = true;
        }
        else
            new Modules.Globals().MsgBoxEx("Kan het bestaande model '" + strModel + "' niet kopieren.", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return blnRetVal;

    }
```

Comment: There are several references undefined in your code.  `m_strModelMarker + strModel;` are both undefined, `objRange` is undefined.  And I think that you are using aliases for your references.. something like `using Alias = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;` Correct?  I also dont know where you are getting Scripting.Dictionary.

Comment: let us suppose that we have 'string m_strModelMarker; string strModel;' and their combined value is equal to 'Carma DocSys~Brief'. It does not work if i don't use alias. It does not have any relation with the scripting.dictionary. Also, please note that this is just a piece of code.

Comment: @RizwanAnsari can you try and run a similar code from within Word? Use the VBScript editor from the developer tab in Word.

Comment: @Nir Kornfeld i am already running the code from within Word.

Comment: You're using a dot.net addin, your code is C#. 
Please try to do the same from **VBScript** and not dot.net using interop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to duplicate your error, however I am able to get your code to run with a few changes.  Let me know if I've misinterpreted.

Note the `Missing` variable used instead of `objRange`.  I've also removed variables that were not applicable.

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Alias = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

public Test()
{
    var doc = new Alias.Document();
    var doc2 = new Alias.Document();
    var t = this.CloneModel(ref doc, ref doc2);
}
private bool CloneModel(ref Alias.Document objTargetDocument, ref Alias.Document objSourceDocument)
{
    var missing = Type.Missing;
    Word.Shape objShape;
    objShape = objTargetDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationUpward, 0, 0, 0, 0, ref missing); <== note the missing here instead of objRange

    objShape.Name = "Carma DocSys~Brief"; // no longer throwing exceptions (hard coded string)
    objShape.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
    return true;
}
```

If this is NOT the problem, then I would suggest that you are having trouble with permissions to the file as the error message suggests.

Comment: objTargetDocument is a targeting word Document, having values accourding to variables which are defined in word template. and about objRange ' Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range objRange;' 'objRange = objTargetDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range.Duplicate;'

Comment: and i am login from Administrator account.

Comment: Perhaps you could post code that better reflected the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you if I cant get a working code example.  Perhaps if you created a new project and paired down your method to duplicate the problem?

Comment: in my case if i assign more than 17 charactors to 'Word.Shape.Name' then it work perfect as in 'Carma DocSys~brief' there are 18 charactors so this throw exception. What i should do to resolve this problem.

Comment: Thanks every one specially paqogomez, Mistake was in my word document object that was objTargetDocument.